# python program not printing as expected

Tags: python

I have some basic code and cannot figure out why it will not print.
I do not get any errors, but printing total doesn't print anything, even 0.  Can anyone explain this to me?

```
def dashcount(x):
    x.split(' ')
    for num in x:
        total = 0
        if num == "0" or num == "6" or num == "9":
            total += 6

        elif num == "1":
            total += 2

        elif num == "2" or num == "3" or num == "5":
            total += 5

        elif num == "4" or num == "7":
            total += 4

        elif num == "8":
            total += 7
    return total
    print total

dashcount("1234")
```

Comment: put the print statement before the return statement.

Comment: the  result of  `x.split(' ')`  is thrown away. What are you trying to do?

Comment: And put total = 0 before for loop

Answer (score 0):

```
return total
```

This completely exits your function. Any lines after your `return` statement are ignored.

Make sure you `print` before you `return`.

You should also remove `x.split(" ")`. It's not doing anything at the moment.

Comment: Fixed. But now i am having the problem that it is not iterating the string, only return the value from the first index.

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct. The print statement should be at the same indent level as your `for` statement, so that it runs only after the for loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The `return` statement exits your function, why the `print` does not get executed. You may move the `print` into the function or `print dashcount("1234")` instead.

Additionally the `x.split(' ')` doesn't do anything (but it is not neccessary as well, because you are iterating over each digit with `for num in x`). You should also move the `total = 0` in front of the loop.